# Unable to Create Spring Url mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jhipster

I am working on spring.I am unable to create mapping for this url in "abc.com/firstName.lastName" sping.if i have write this code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{path}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@Timed
public void saveProfileMapping(@PathVariable String path)
{
    System.out.println("-------------getting Mapping--------------"+path);
}
```

Then get only firstname i.e lastname is not get in spring.but if write like that

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{firstName}.{lastName}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@Timed
public void saveProfileMapping(@PathVariable String firstName,String lastName)
{
    System.out.println("-------------getting Mapping--------------"+firstName+lastName);
}
```

Same result here get only firstname.

Please need your help..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your method is rerturning void so try with @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)

Comment: Thanks for reply @V-spring but method not given any exception it working fine for me but not get the value of lastname using this mapping.

Comment: have you tried @PathVariable String firstName,@PathVariable String lastName this or  like @PathVariable("lastName") String lastName

Comment: By default the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` ignores the part after the last `.`. So indeed you will never see the `{lastName}`. Next to that your mapping is also wrong your argument isn't annotated with @PathVariable. You will need to configure the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` to include the part after the `.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to PathVariables's:

```
...
public void saveProfileMapping(@PathVariable String firstName,@PathVariable String lastName)
...
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Marten identified the problem correctly. An alternative (easier) solution is to use a regex in the `@RequestMapping` e.g. this matches everything:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/{path:.*}")
 public void saveProfileMapping(@PathVariable String path)
 { ... }
```